# sed or awk replacing text using a text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have been looking into `sed` and `awk`. I have not found an example that shows using a text file (findtext.txt) to scan all *.php files and remove the text.

pretty much I have a block of text that needed to be removed for a bunch of php files.

I know how to use the basic sed command like this

```
sed -i 's/sometext/replacetext/g' *.php
```

What i would like to do is have sed look in findtext.txt grab the block of text and then scan *.php and removed that block of text from the files.

Comment: Edit your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output. You will get out of the answer to your question however much you put into asking it.

Comment: You can create `findtext.txt` that contains your sed script such as `s/sometext/replacetext/g` to replace sometext with replacetext. You can put as much `sed` script as you need including deleting specific lines like `1d`, or `/sometext/,/anothertext/d`. Then use the script like `sed -i -f findtext.txt *.php`.

Comment: and if  you mean 'remove malware code inserted into my website' then you can start crying now (sorry). You can search here for solutions, but they are very brittle. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

There are two challenges:

- Using text stored in a variable or file that should be treated *literally* when used as the regex argument to `sed`'s `s///` function presents the challenge of having to escape regex metacharacters in that text.
- Additionally, since you're talking about a *block* of text that's stored in file `findtext.txt`, I assume you're talking about a *multi*-line solution - whereas `sed` is *single line*-oriented by default.

The following solution addresses both challenges:

```
# Read the multiline search string into a variable 
# and quote it to ensure literal treatment when used as a regex.
sometextQuoted=$(sed -e 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g; $!a\'$'\n''\\n' < 'findtext.txt' | 
  tr -d '\n')

# Now process the *.php files:
# Read each file *as a whole* before performing the string replacement.
sed ':a; $!{N;ba}; s/'"$sometextQuoted"'/replacetext/g' *.php
```

- The solution is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573/45375) of mine, wich explains the `sed` command used to quote (escape) the search text (`sometextQuoted=...`) in detail.
- `':a; $!{N;ba}` is a standard `sed` idiom that reads an entire file at once.
- Note how `"$sometextQuoted"` is *spliced into* the otherwise single-quoted `sed` script to avoid confusion over what the shell interprets up front vs. what `sed` ends up seeing.
- Note that if you also wanted to read the *replacement* text (`replacetext` in your example) from a variable/file, a *different* form of quoting (escaping) would be required - again, see the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573/45375).

<sup>Note: The 2nd `sed` command requires *GNU* `sed`, which I assume you're using (`-i` without an argument doesn't work with BSD/OSX `sed`); it *is* possible, but more complex, to make this work with BSD/OSX `sed`.

Also, I've omitted `-i` from the command so you can check the results first without replacing the original files.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Assign the content of `findtext.txt` to a bash variable, and use that variable in sed substitution. Below is a one line solution. I am not sure if it works if there are more than one line in `findtext.txt`.

```
$ findtext=$(cat findtext.txt) && sed -i.bak -e "s/$findtext/bbbb/g" *.php
```

Comment: This will not solve the stated problem of " have a block of text that needed to be removed ", assuming that a "block of text" has multiple lines (a safe assumption in my book). Good luck to all.